# gsl complex matrix * complex vector

Tags: c, matrix, gsl

Can somebody help me figure out how to do this operation.  I'm looking at the documentation, but its been so long since I've had to do any linear algebra type stuff I'm a little lost.

I have a 14x14 complex matrix called Y and a complex vector called I.  I need to multiply them and set the result to a complex vector named IL.

So far I have figured out that I need to use:

```
gsl_blas_zgemv (CBLAS_TRANSPOSE_t TransA, const gsl_complex alpha, const 
                 gsl_matrix_complex * A, const gsl_vector_complex * x, const  
                 gsl_complex beta, gsl_vector_complex * y)
```

But I'm not sure what goes where.  Not sure what goes where.  Something like this?  but what are the alpha and beta?

```
gsl_blas_zgemv(CblasNoTrans, ???, &Y, &I, ???, IL);
```

Comment: The function with no `CblasNOTrans` is 
    y := alpha*A*x + beta*y
So I would call it as
    `gsl_blas_zgemv(CblasNoTrans, GSL_COMPLEX_ONE, &Y, &I,     GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO, IL);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  But what are GSL_COMPLEX_ONE & GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO?  Do I need to define these and if so how?

Comment: There is an example of a double at http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/BLAS-Examples.html

Also if you look at the source of BLAS http://www.netlib.org/blas/zgemv.f
you can see the what is happening.

In your case `IL = y`, `Y = A` and `I = x`, so aren't you wanting `IL = Y*I`?

GSL_COMPLEX_ONE and ZERO are defined in `gsl_complex_math.h`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing what you are actually doing, it looks like you haven't included the right headers. As the following works without errors for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int size = 14;
    gsl_matrix_complex *A = NULL;
    gsl_vector_complex *x = NULL;
    gsl_vector_complex *y = NULL;

    A = gsl_matrix_complex_alloc(size, size);
    x = gsl_vector_complex_alloc(size);
    y = gsl_vector_complex_alloc(size);

    gsl_matrix_complex_set_all(A, GSL_COMPLEX_ONE);
    gsl_vector_complex_set_all(x, GSL_COMPLEX_ONE);
    gsl_vector_complex_set_all(y, GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO);

    gsl_blas_zgemv(CblasNoTrans, GSL_COMPLEX_ONE, A, x,
            GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO, y);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

And compiling with

```
gcc -o test -I/opt/local/include/gsl -L/opt/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas test.c
```

(yes, I am on a Mac using MacPorts).

Comment: Oh, Yes, I was missing gsl/gsl_complex_math.h so I was just defining my own, which worked, but now that I know GSL_COMPLEX_ONE and GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO are in that header I'll just use that.  Thanks

Comment: `-I/opt/local/include/gsl -L/opt/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas` can be replaced by `\`gsl-config --cflags --libs\`` including the backticks.