# Complex Matrix Multiplication using gsl

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers, gsl

I have a very simple question -- I just want to multiply two matrices with complex entries together in gsl in C. So for example I want to define a function

```
gsl_matrix_complex *multiply( gsl_matrix_complex *A, gsl_matrix_complex *B ) {
???
}
```

I've seen it done when the entries are doubles, but I can't figure out the appropriate generalization. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gsl complex matrix \* complex vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572823/gsl-complex-matrix-complex-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To multiply matrices in GSL you need to use the slightly cryptic [BLAS interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Level-3-GSL-BLAS-Interface.html#Level-3-GSL-BLAS-Interface).

Assuming that the matrices you are going to multiply don't have any known structure (e.g. are symmetric or hermitian etc.). The appropriate function to use would be `gsl_blas_zgemm`. The translation of the seemingly random string of letters in the function name is:

```
z  = double precision complex
ge = general matrices
mm = matrix-matrix multiplication
```

(For a list of all the abbreviations see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/BLAS-Support.html#BLAS-Support))

Using the information in the docs we could then write your function as

```c
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

gsl_matrix_complex *multiply( gsl_matrix_complex *A, gsl_matrix_complex *B)
{
    gsl_matrix_complex *result = gsl_matrix_complex_alloc(A->size1, B->size2);

    gsl_blas_zgemm(CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                   GSL_COMPLEX_ONE, A, B,
                   GSL_COMPLEX_ZERO, result);

    return result;
}
```

Note that instead of allocating the result matrix in the multiplication function it would instead be better practice to pass in one that has already been allocated in the calling function, for example with the signature:

```c
void multiply*(gsl_matrix_complex *A, gsl_matrix_complex *B, gsl_matrix_complex *result);
```

and then omit the allocation step and the explicit return. The reason for this is that it allows you to minimize the number of heap allocations your code performs as well as making it harder for you to accidentally write code that leaks memory.